# ASP control disappears when updated with ajax (telerik)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik

I have an asp button "btn" and a label "lbl". When I click the button, the label's text should change but instead the label disappears. This is my aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js">
            </asp:ScriptReference>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js">
            </asp:ScriptReference>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js">
            </asp:ScriptReference>
        </Scripts>
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btn">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="lbl" UpdatePanelCssClass="" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<div>
    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server" HorizontalAlign="NotSet" ID="pnl">
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="test" ID="btn" OnClick="btn_OnClick"/>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="test" ID="lbl"></asp:Label>
    </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
</div>
</form>
```

And this is my code behind:

```
protected void btn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl.Text = "test2";
    }
```

I'm sure this should work.. maybe it is something related with the latest telerik dll (2014Q1) or am I missing something?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not nest AJAX settings and a RadAJaxPanel. Remove the RadAjaxPanel and see how it goes: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-controls-in-ajaxpanel-and-ajaxsettings.html.